# What Google services do the Google Pixel phones require using?

Tags: google-play-store, gmail, google, google-pixel, google-pixel-2

What Google services do the Google Pixel phones require using?  Or can they be used without using Google products?

For example, do they require using a Google account?  If so, do they require using the Google Play Store?  What about Google Drive?  Do they force syncing contacts and calendars to Google servers?

Can all the Google apps be disabled on them?

When answering please specify if your answer applies to the original Pixel or the Pixel 2, or (if you know) both.

Answer (score 1):

This applies to both Pixel devices. The first time you start the phone, you'll be asked to sync it with a Google account.

Google Play Store is optional. You can download third-party apps on the devices.

You will not be asked to sync contacts or calendar to Google servers.

But it only makes sense to buy the Google Pixel if you're fine with using a Google account.